# How do reset Debian 10.9 root and login password?

Tags: debian, sudo, grub

I'm currently using **Debian 10.9** buster release with **gnome 3.30.2**

I forgot my login and root password but I've had **auto-login enabled** i.e., I'm automatically logged in after a reboot or power on but, I'm unable to perform admin tasks / tasks related to **`sudo`** command.

So to reset my password, most of the ways I know of, need **sudo** previliges and the one way which doesn't involve any use of gnome session terminal is through the use of **advanced settings** from **grub menu** but as you can see, my grub disappears in just a flash ( inferring from the **grub config** below) i.e., grub is hidden and the timeout is zero, precluding me from accessing **`advanced settings`** via **`grub`** and ironically, I need **`sudo`** previliges to reconfig my **grub**

My grub config looks something like this -

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Is there a way out of this predicament ?

I need this issue to be resolved asap, since I've got glut of (incomplete) work to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a live usb of any linux os and boot into the live environment, then mount your root partiton in the live environment and edit the `/etc/sudoers` file in the mounted partition and add the following line. Say your username is prithvi, then `prithvi ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`, Now you have root privileges without root password. Boot into your machine and change password of superuser using `sudo passwd` command

Comment: Will it not ask me `sudo` password for **mounting** and accessing `sudoers` file ?

Comment: @prithvi It will not ask for root password in live environment. You will have root privilages in live environment by default.

Comment: Well, you solution made my day. It worked. Thanks a lot, fayad.

Comment: I suggest you to remove the line you added in `/etc/sudoers` file, after changing root password. Also if this has helped, you may accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've removed `NOPASSWD` from `/etc/sudoers` &  accepted your answer as well.